# Are $\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$ imaginary numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

## Background

I am teaching senior high school students about the structure of numbers.
Start from defining $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ as the rational and real numbers respectively, we can define $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ as the irrational numbers.

I am trying to use the same logic to define imaginary numbers by making use of the relationship between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$. Another definition for imaginary numbers is

> numbers that become negative under squaring operation.

[image]

Let $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ be the complex and real number sets respectively. Are $\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$  imaginary numbers?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- only the **purely** real numbers have been cast out, right, $\mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{R}$ contains all complex numbers except purely real numbers. For e.g $1+2\iota$ is still there.

Comment: I agree with @Fawkes4494d3; a [purely imaginary complex number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PurelyImaginaryNumber.html) has no real part

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3, oh, yes you're right. (>ლ), $\sqrt{-1}$ should delete it

Comment: math educators community maybe of your (future). interests.

Comment: I would simply avoid each potential misleading notation as $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: Then, what notation should we use to represent imaginary numbers?

Comment: Just first define them ... You're "trying to use the same logic to define imaginary numbers", but in fact: one can't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Imaginary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) are real multiples of $\mathrm{i}$.  So the complex number $1+\mathrm{i} \in \Bbb{C} \smallsetminus \Bbb{R}$ is neither real nor imaginary.

Comment: @Artificial Stupidity, R lies inside C, ofc. A complex number is made of real and imaginary part.. so I don't quite get you.

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- : A real number has zero imaginary part and an imaginary number has zero real part.  Any complex number with neither part zero is neither real nor imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "imaginary." Perhaps you mean an element of $\Bbb{C}$ of the form $ai$ for $a\in \Bbb{R}$ in which case this is false. Indeed, in the complex plane you have removed only the "$x$-axis" so that
$$\Bbb{C}\setminus \Bbb{R}=\{a+bi:b
\ne 0\:\text{and}\:a,b\in \Bbb{R}\}.$$

Comment: Shouldn’t this be the set of all $bi$’s ? Where $a = 0$? Since you’re taking out the “real part” of the complex number - giving a simply pure imaginary number.

Comment: It's possible I'm misunderstanding, but for instance like in Eric Towers' answer, $1+i\in \Bbb{C}\setminus \Bbb{R}$, which is not of the form $bi$. (Edit: there was a mistake, but the mistake was that it should be $b\ne 0$ rather than $a\ne 0$).

Comment: Gotcha! Your correction makes sense now. Thanks for your time.